# Cordova platform add ios - not able to add App & Splash icons

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

Getting below error for all icons which are located in res folder

```
cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT):/Users/ABC/myApp-web-p2/platforms/ios/my_App/Resources/icons/icon-60@2x.png
```

Was trying on MAC OS. Can someone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Any solution? Not able to copy

Comment: This was happening for me on an Ionic 1 project when building with Ionic CLI 3 and Cordova 7. I updated `cordova-ios` to a more recent version (4.1.1->4.5.3) and am not seeing the issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sudo while run your command:

```
sudo
```